# ShouldMapTo - Data not in the url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib-3

I'm trying to unit test my routes, and I'm starting to hit a problem.  Some of the action method parameters won't be coming from the URL anymore, but instead will be supplied by an action filter, based on this article: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/21/manipulating-action-method-parameters.aspx

The problem is that I have a url: `/some/path/id` which maps to an action method `public ViewResult Action(int id, Guid sessionId)` where `sessionId` is being added to the action parmaters by the action filter.  There's now now way that I can see to make this test pass without making `Guid` a `Guid?`:

```
"~/some/path/1".ShouldMapTo<SomeController>(x => x.Action(1, <anyGuid>));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's now no way that I can see to make this test pass without making Guid a Guid?

Well actually there is a way.

If you are using Rhino Mocks (which is bundled by default with `MvcContrib.TestHelper`, so you are already implicitly using it):

```
"~/home/action/1"
    .ShouldMapTo<SomeController>(x => x.Action(1, Arg<Guid>.Matches(y => true)));
```

and if you are using Moq:

```
"~/some/action/1"
    .ShouldMapTo<SomeController>(x => x.Action(1, It.IsAny<Guid>()));
```

and if you are using some other mocking framework check the documentation about the syntax that would allow you to specify a parameter constraint that could be anything.

Comment: Wow, I was wishing that I could just use Moq's `It.IsAny<T>` but I didn't expect it to actually work.  Thanks!